# Rails pagination error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I'm using the will_paginate plugin and I get the following error only when I'm running on a server rather than locally:

```
undefined method `total_pages' for []:Array
Extracted source (around line #8):

5:  <% session[:page] = params[:page] %>
6:  <h2>Previous Scenario</h2>
7: <% end %>
8:  <%= will_paginate @scenarios, :next_label => 'Older', :prev_label => 'Newer' %>
9: <div class="box">
10: <% for scenario in @scenarios %>
11:     <% @created = scenario.created_at %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, `@scenarios` is an ordinary Array for you and it can't be from `Scenario.paginate()` method because that one always returns a `WillPaginate::Collection` object.

Answer (score 1):

Does your controller have the other half of the equation, e.g.

```
@scenario = Scenario.paginate(:page => params[:page]||1)
```

Alternatively I think you might have a plugin on the server side that is converting your Active Record set into a plain array. I'd need a bit more info to look at that.

Comment: @scenarios = Scenario.paginate(:page => params[:page],
    :per_page => 1,
    :order => 'created_at DESC',
    :conditions => {:sim_id => session[:sim_id]})

Comment: What does

    logger.error @scenarios.inspect 

give on production and dev? 

Also try

<%= @scenarios.inspect %>

in the views. Are they the same?